# Express route returning 404 error

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

The express route in my node app is returning a 404 error. It works locally but on the production server it returns a 404 error (bear in mind that I changed the AJAX url to the one on my production server before uploading). My code:

**server.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../public');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.post('/active-screens', function(req, res) {
  res.send('route works!');
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

**index.js:**

```
function checkRoute(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/active-screens",
    type: "POST"
  })
  .success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}

checkRoute();
```

Comment: I think it's a CORS problem

Comment: is there a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. error ?

Comment: @WejdDAGHFOUS it was a CORS issue. That fixed it - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a CORS issue as pointed out by @WejdDAGHFOUS.

I updated my **server.js** to this:

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../public');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.post('/active-screens', cors(), function(req, res) {
  res.send('route works!');
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```